# Fast way for getting unique values from iterators

Tags: python, performance, python-2.7, iterator

It is well known that iterators show a better performance than common list comprehensions:

```
In [8]: from random import random

In [10]: %timeit [random() for i in range(10000000)]
1 loops, best of 3: 883 ms per loop

In [11]: %timeit (random() for i in range(10000000))
10 loops, best of 3: 176 ms per loop
```

However, the performance gain disappears when I'm trying to get unique values from iterator:

```
In [12]: %timeit set([random() for i in range(10000000)])
1 loops, best of 3: 5.06 s per loop

In [13]: %timeit set((random() for i in range(10000000)))
1 loops, best of 3: 5.02 s per loop
```

I wonder if there are fast and generic methods of getting unique values for an iterable objects? (I'm aware of [`numpy.unique`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html), but I often have to work with strings).

Comment: The `[11]` test is not what you think it is. It just _defines_ a generator, without consuming it - that's why it's so quick.

Comment: @georg, OK. Therefore, `[12]` and `[13]` tests' equality is a consistent result, isn't it? And there is no way to improve it?

Comment: Correct. If you consume everything, all iterables (gens, LC's, lists) will have comparable performance. Generators are memory-savers, not speed-boosters.

Comment: @georg is spot on - the benefits of iterators (and the handy functionality in `itertools`) come in when *you don't need all the elements at once*. Rather than fill a chunk of memory with a list `range(10000000)` you can create an `xrange(10000000)` that produces one number at a time. The disadvantages are that you can't go back or index arbitrarily, but in many circumstances working element-by-element is the best way to go.

Comment: List comprehensions are actually known to be faster in most practical cases. but yes iterators can be much faster when they short circuit and save a lot of processing time and memory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @georg `[11]` is fast because it essentially does nothing.

If you are using Python 2, `range()` creates a list, while `xrange()` would not. This gives:

```
In [1]: from random import random

In [2]: timeit set([random() for i in xrange(10000000)])
1 loops, best of 3: 6.11 s per loop

In [3]: timeit set(random() for i in xrange(10000000))
1 loops, best of 3: 5.61 s per loop
```

Which shows a little time gain. Anyway the main gain of `[3]` over `[2]` is of course a memory gain.

To answer your question, using `set()` and making sure not to create a list in between is the best (and most Pythonic) way to get unique values from a generator.

Answer (score 1):

While `set` will guarantee uniqueness, it destroys order in a fashion that makes your sequence less random, and you're not guaranteed to have as many items as you generated. A different method is to make sure all the items generated are unique in the first place, as shown in [random.sample](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/random.html#random.sample):

```
sample(xrange(10000000), 60)
```

This works because [`xrange`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#xrange) is not only iterable but follows the sequence protocol (is indexable and has length). The question refers to "getting unique values for an iterable objects" which doesn't quite describe what the samples shown do. Perhaps if we knew what the task is a more suitable answer could be developed.